# Installing GDAL on Linx Mint

Tags: python, linux, gdal, linux-mint

I've installed GDAL using Anaconda on my Linux machine

```
conda install gdal
```

but I can't load it. If I run Python

```
   import gdal
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-27bf4694dd2b> in <module>()
----> 1 import gdal

/home/auerilas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gdal.py in <module>()
      1 # import osgeo.gdal as a convenience
----> 2 from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn
      3 deprecation_warn('gdal')
      4
      5 from osgeo.gdal import *

/home/auerilas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in <module>()
     19                 fp.close()
     20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
     22     del swig_import_helper
     23 else:

/home/auerilas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py in swig_import_helper()
     15         if fp is not None:
     16             try:
---> 17                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
     18             finally:
     19                 fp.close()

/home/auerilas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    240                 return load_dynamic(name, filename, opened_file)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
    244         return load_package(name, filename)

/home/auerilas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    340         spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343
    344 else:

ImportError: libnetcdf.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I run into the same error if I try to run gdal from the command line

```
gdalwarp
gdalwarp: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, it looks as though libnetcdf is installed:

```
ls -R | grep libnetcdf
libnetcdf-4.4.1-0.json
libnetcdf.a
libnetcdf.la
libnetcdf.settings
libnetcdf.so
libnetcdf.so.11
libnetcdf.so.11.0.3
libnetcdf-4.4.1-0
libnetcdf-4.4.1-0.tar.bz2
./anaconda3/pkgs/libnetcdf-4.4.1-0:
./anaconda3/pkgs/libnetcdf-4.4.1-0/bin:
./anaconda3/pkgs/libnetcdf-4.4.1-0/include:
./anaconda3/pkgs/libnetcdf-4.4.1-0/info:
./anaconda3/pkgs/libnetcdf-4.4.1-0/lib:
libnetcdf.a
libnetcdf.la
libnetcdf.settings
libnetcdf.so
libnetcdf.so.11
libnetcdf.so.11.0.3
./anaconda3/pkgs/libnetcdf-4.4.1-0/lib/pkgconfig:
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I've tried compiling gdal from source and that doesn't work, I run into an error about gdalinfo missing. However, gdal config works

```
gdal-config --version
2.0.0
```

and I've also tried running

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev
```

**UPDATE**

I hacked together an update by following the broken links. When I installed gdal, I had libnetcdf.so.11, libkea.so.1.4.6, and libhdf5_cpp.so.12. But gdal was looking for libnetcdf.so.7, libkea.so.1.4.5, and libhdf5_cpp.10. I made the following symlinks:

```
cd ~/anaconda3/lib
ln -s libnetcdf.so.11 libnetcdf.so.7
ln -s libkea.so.1.4.6 libkea.so.1.4.5
ln -s libhdf5_cpp.12 libhdf5_cpp.10
```

and it works fine. Something was broken in the install where gdal was attempting to find the libraries by specific version rather than by the generic libnetcdf.so. If gdal uses the generic, non-versioned files, those act as symbolic links to the current version. Any thoughts on where to post this for gdal/Anaconda devs?

Comment: although not a direct solution to your problem, I use software that uses gdal as a dependency so it installs it for me. You could try it out in a separate environment using 'conda env create au-eoed/au-osgeo-lnx' and then
'source activate au-osgeo-lnx'. An ugly short-term fix perhaps?

Comment: I can try, but I'm not sure if its the install that is the issue..

Comment: Although your fix appears to work fine, I would be wary. You're linking potentially incompatible libraries which could break things (in a confusing way in the future). I'd recommend installing the correct libnetcdf version (7) - maybe with something like linuxbrew where you can specify the version http://linuxbrew.sh/ ... Or get the conda devs to update their package :-)